# unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int' in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Can anyone please help me understand where I am going wrong?

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
ctr_x = []
tl_list = []

df = pd.read_csv('ring_1_05_sam.csv')
ctr_x = df.iloc[8:12, 0:1]
ctr_y = df.iloc[8:12, 1:2]
ctr_x = (ctr_x.to_string(index=False, header=False))
ctr_y = (ctr_y.to_string(index=False, header=False))
tl_list.append((str(ctr_x - 30),str(ctr_y - 30)))

print(tl_list)
```

I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "annotation.py", line 9, in <module>
tl_list.append((str(ctr_x - 30),str(ctr_y - 30)))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
```

As mentioned in comments:

**I am trying to subtract each value by 30 and store in `tl_list[]`.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Disclaimer: The solutions below haven't been tested yet.*

#### Edit:

You can do

```
ctr_x = df.iloc[8:12, 0:1] - 30   ## subtracts each element by 30
ctr_y = df.iloc[8:12, 1:2] - 30   ## ditto
ctr_x = (ctr_x.to_string(index=False, header=False))
ctr_y = (ctr_y.to_string(index=False, header=False))
tl_list.append((ctr_x, ctr_y))    ## appends [tuple of] string[s]
```

#### Old Answer:

```
ctr_x = (ctr_x.to_string(index=False, header=False))
```

This will line will make `ctr_x` a string, so it has type **`str`**.

This bit causes the error:

```
ctr_x - 30
```

Why? Simply said, because you **can't** subtract from a string (aka, you can't use the *minus operand*). Instead, you might use

```
int(ctr_x) - 30
```

This casts `ctr_x` as an integer first, which *then* allows you to use the minus operand.

---

Some side-notes:

You declared `ctr_x = []` near the top of your code, but don't seem to be using any list functionalities with it.

Comment: I tried but now i get this error : ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Comment: Ah ok. That means the cast `int(ctr_x)` is failing. Which means `ctr_x` seems to have some non-0-9 characters. Run through a debugger, or print out `ctr_x` and see what you're getting.

Comment: Oke. printring ctr_x gives the output 

1537.00
1537.00
1536.25
1536.50

and after modifying tl_list with the line
tl_list.append((str(int(ctr_x) - 30),str(int(ctr_y) - 30)))
i get the error

  File "annotation.py", line 19, in <module>
    tl_list.append((str(int(ctr_x) - 30),str(int(ctr_y) - 30)))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1537.00\n1537.00\n1536.25\n
1536.50'

Comment: and thanks for reminding me that i did not define ctr_y. I updated the code

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do with `- 30`... are you wanting to subtract all 4 values by 30?

Comment: yes exactly. i am trying to subtract each value by 30 and store in  tl_list[]. ctr_x gives me center 'x' coordinates from the csv file(about 3000 values in total). so i want to subtract 30 from each value to get top_left value and store

Comment:  Why not just keep the dataframe/series, you can use `- 30` there. What's the use of `.to_string(index=False, header=False)`?

Comment: .to_string(index=False, header=False). This is to remove the index and header. I am going to create an xml file using the tl_list values and if i dont use this line i get the header and index which i dont want

Comment: Alternatively, i tried ctr_x = df.iloc[5:30, 0:1].valuescommand which gets rid of the header and index, but my result is enclosed in []. I am not sure how [] brackets affects the xml file, so i can get rid of them by writing a script but i was looking for solutions to generate date without the boxes

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to subtract each value by 30 and store in tl_list[].

String conversion is distracting and unnecessary. You also don't need to explicitly instantiate and append to lists. Use [`pd.Series.tolist`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tolist.html) instead:

```
res_x = (df.iloc[8:12, 0] - 30).tolist()
res_y = (df.iloc[8:12, 1] - 30).tolist()

res = [res_x, res_y]
```

Or combine your operations and use [`np.ndarray.tolist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html):

```
res = (df.iloc[8:12, 0:2] - 30).values.tolist()
```

Comment: although when i try to combine my operations i get an error 
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'tolist'

So instead i just used
res = (df.iloc[8:12, 0:2] - 30).values.tolist()

Comment: @Shameendra, See update, you need `np.ndarray.tolist` for a dataframe.